# Inconsistent 'Unknown type name' error in protocol referencing NSManagedObject subclasses

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4, protocols, nsmanagedobject

I have two protocols declared in my project. The first one I wrote is named `SSSelectingCategory.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SSSelectingCategory <NSObject>

@required
@property (nonatomic, strong) SSCategory *selectedCategory;

@end
```

The second one is `SSSelectingIcon.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SSSelectingIcon <NSObject>

@required
@property (nonatomic, strong) SSIcon *selectedIcon;

@end
```

The strange thing is that the first protocol compiles without any error or warning, while the second one is throwing the `Unknown type name 'SSIcon'`.

I know the answer to this problem is to use a forward-class declaration in my second protocol like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class SSIcon;

@protocol SSSelectingIcon <NSObject>

@required
@property (nonatomic, strong) SSIcon *selectedIcon;

@end
```

But now this makes me think the `SSSelectingCategory.h` protocol shouldn't have compiled at all in the first place, as I didn't put any explicit `#import` or forward-class declaration of any sort.

I could quiet the compiler and go on coding, but I want to understand if there's something weird going on with Xcode or if I'm missing some fine point, as both protocols are really simple. Could there be a problem with the `SSCategory` and/or `SSIcon` classes, as they're both `NSManagedObject`s and there's a relationship connecting the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler compiles the .m files, which in turn include the .h files.

So I assume that in the .m file where "SSSelectingCategory.h" is included, `SSCategory` is defined before, so that the compiler has no problem compiling the protocol.

If, on the other hand, "SSSelectingIcon.h" is included without having defined `SSIcon` before, the compiler would abort with an error there.

In any case, it makes sense to include the required interfaces in the .h file (or forward declare the required classes), because that enables code-completion in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks Martin R, it's as you describe it. Another lesson learned!